# Stdout function with line return automatic - PHP

Tags: php, echo

I am coming from the JavaScript world, and I am searching for the best way, or the best function to echo something like "console.log()" in JavaScript which have a break line between different execution.

Until now I am forcing to do things like `echo("blaba\n")`, but "\n" everywhere is not terrible. What is the good way to do this?

Comment: `function log($msg) { echo $msg . "\n"; }`?

Comment: You can use `print_r($elem);` is prints the entire object as key value instead of just printing the type.

Comment: Define your own function which echos with \n

Comment: If for the purposes of logging, you'd use [`error_log`](http://php.net/error_log) or similar. stdout and `console.log` aren't really comparable. For what purpose do you want this?

Comment: Sorry, bad explanations of my part, I am coming from node.js where stdout & console.log are the same if working on the backend side.

Comment: Well, on PHP stdout is the returned output, and stderr is for logging. So you're really asking for the best logging solution (?).

Comment: I think that is the same in every langage on unix, stdout is the classic log output, stderr are the log for error warning & else .. isn't it?

Comment: stdout isn't *log* output, it's the result that will be returned to the browser. Yes, PHP is very traditional UNIX in this respect, acting as an invoke-once-return-result program. node is different in that it's its own server returning many results to many requests directly on the socket, leaving its stdout entirely free for other purposes.

Comment: Hum... I can use php in cli command, is that way my stdout is my console like any other langage?

Comment: Depends on what you want. The *return value/result* of your code always goes to stdout (`echo`, `print`). In a web server scenario that's returned to the browser, on the CLI that's simply your stdout. For *logging*, you'd use `error_log` or write to stderr or to a file.

Comment: Re *""\n" everywhere is not terrible"*. Don't you mean *""\n" everywhere is terrible"* (without the *"not"*)?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is a better solution, but if you want a way to shorthand the output of a new line, you could create a function that automatically adds it for you.

For example:

```php
function echo_br( $text = '' ) {

    // Echo text but add new line at the end
    echo $text . "\n";

}
```

Then use the function:

```php
echo_br( 'Hello World' );
```

It's worth noting that the console in a browser accessed via JavaScript is fundamentally different to that of PHP so I'm not aware of anything like this because the use cases are completely different and logs are displayed in a list of rows in a browser UI.

Comment: Ok thanks, noted it. I will use dedicated function so ;)